# How did Jewish scholars deal with supposed "scribal errors" in the Tanach

Tags: tanach, rabbis, contradiction, biblical-criticism

There are some contemporary Christians (Evangelicals, etc) say that there are contradictions in the Old Testament caused by scribal errors (Who Killed Goliath? (2 Samuel 21:19; 1 Chronicles 20:5), How Old Was Jehoiachin When He Began His Reign? (2 Kings 24:8; 2 Chronicles 36:9), Hadadezer or Hadarezer? (2 Samuel 8:3, 16, 19; 1 Chronicles 18:3; KJV and ASV))

How did Jewish scholars, like Rashi, deal with these contradictions?

Comment: Every supposed error is its own case that needs to be assessed. This question is too broad. Perhaps limit your question to one or a couple examples, which I believe are already addressed on this site.

Comment: The Talmud already dealt with it: https://www.sefaria.org/Tractate_Soferim.6.4?vhe=Talmud_Bavli,_Vilna_1883_ed.&lang=bi:  "R. Simeon b. Laḳish said: Three scrolls of the Torah were found in the Temple: In one found the expression of "ma‘on", and in the other two it was written "me‘onah". In one they found it written, "And he sent the za‘aṭuṭë" and in the other two "And he sent na‘arë". ... So they adopted the reading of the two and discarded that of the one."